# Pressing "^" changes keyboard controls in Overleaf's LaTeX code editor

Tags: overleaf, keyboard

In some cases when I press "^" and spacebar afterward, my keyboard seems to change its controls. I cannot press tab to autocomplete commands anymore, I cannot delete blank lines and pressing "tab" multiple times opens options like the zoom on the right side of the screen or my searchbar. Otherwise the keyboard inputs seem to be the same and I can only notice it while using LaTex in Overleaf.

I use an apple MacBook Air and Safari as my internet browser and unmodified German keyboard configs.

Edit: I'd like to disable that feature since it's annoying when I try to place a superscript in math mode and write a command afterwards. The "^" button is left to the number 1 in the German keyboard if that helps.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: By "^", do you mean the control key, or do you mean shift-6 (on a US keyboard)?

Comment: Overleaf-specific questions should be directed to Overleaf's Helpdesk.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.